# Windows API Crash when window displayed

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a Windows application. It should be noted that this issue only occurs on certain computers (it runs fine on mine). I create the window as follows:

```
RECT wr = {0, 0, rOp->resX, rOp->resY};
AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);
WNDCLASS wc;
wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hAppInst;
wc.hIcon         = NULL;
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = L"App";
if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
{
    return false;
}
hAppWnd = CreateWindow( L"App", lpWindowName, WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED, 0, 0, wr.right - wr.left, wr.bottom - wr.top, NULL, NULL, hAppInst, NULL );
```

On the PCs of two of my friends, this crashes when the window is displayed. If I remove WS_VISIBLE, the application continues to run fine until ShowWindow is called, upon which time it crashes. My friends report seeing a white window immediately before it crashes, so the window appears to be being displayed.

Does anyone have any theories as to why this might be happening?

EDIT: WndProc is as follows:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        reng->draw();
        return 0;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return 1;
    default:
        return reng->DefProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

DefProc is a function pointer to this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DefProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case GM_NEWGAME:
        newGame();
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

(GM_NEWGAME is a user-defined message)

The DefProc function pointer is always set before the window is created.

Comment: It's clearly getting as far as creating the window, then something's going wrong, probably when `WM_CREATE` is sent to the window, so @gunner is right: your WndProc is where you should be looking.

Comment: also post the `reng->draw()` function

Comment: If you run this code on a 64-bit operating system then you might not see hard exceptions, it has a nasty habit of swallowing them.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for Win32 Exceptions.  It might be too late and Windows has already installed an appcompat shim.  Rename the output .exe for a Q&D fix for that.

Comment: @lazy_banana No need, if reng->draw is indeed being called at that point then that would definitely explain the crash. Why would it, though? Even if WM_PAINT were posted, am I incorrect in assuming that it shouldn't be sent to WndProc until the message loop is reached (which is far enough into the program that reng->draw will no longer cause a crash)?

Comment: @user1476981 makes sense, then how did you define `GM_NEWGAME`? if you did it wrong it might conflict with and existing message. The correct way is `WM_USER+x` where you chose the `x`

Comment: Have you stepped trough the creation process? Also, what exactly is the crash your receiving? It's possible that somewhere in your code you've referenced an API that may not be available on their machines, and that would cause a crash too, The acutal error message it's self would be a great help in tracking this down, also the operating systems of your "two friends" need to be told as well, as well as what version of the windows sdk are you using.

Comment: lazy_banana: WM_USER+0.
@johnathon My friend reported the following details:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: RefracGame.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 4fe5054e
  Fault Module Name: RefracGame.exe
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4fe5054e
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00002bef
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID: 3081

They're both using Windows 7, the same operating system as me. As for Windows SDK version, whatever comes with Windows/Visual Studio I guess (just included Windows.h).

Comment: @lazy_banana actually WM_USER+x is aligned with some windows messages values used by the windows.h file. it's better to use WM_APP+x

Comment: @user1476981 that appears to be an access violation, either you have something that you are trying to access that hasn't actually been created yet, Always check your creation routines, make sure every pointer is not NULL before you try to use it, also, always check the return codes of api calls if they have them (hresults, ect) and if not, DO check that the pointer you created with the api call is not null, and if it is, and the function does not use hresults, call GetLastError().

Answer (score 1):

The must be in your wndproc. Maybe there is a synchronization problem between an object creation and its use in there.

Comment: Posted my WndProc. WM_PAINT wouldn't be posted at the same time as WM_CREATE, would it?

Answer (score 1):

As the code you have posted here has nothing that can explicitly cause a crash, and as it only happens when the window is actually shown, it looks like the bug is inside the draw() method.

The best solution would be to build a debug version of your application and ask your friend to create a dump file with task manager when it crashes. They you can open it in Visual Studio and see the exact line in your code that caused the crash.